# Extruding faces are locked to a translation along a odd axis

Tags: modeling, transforms

Now, when I press <kbd>E</kbd> for extrusion, this wired thing happens:

[image: extrusion along the face normals]

And then if I try to move it, this happens:

[image: faces in model after being moved]

This also happens when I try to scale.

Comment: What exactly is the weird thing that happens? What did you expect to happen?

Comment: I will explain:

Comment: you have the Subsurf modifier displayed in edit mode and you are using Individual origins

Comment: what are individual origins?

Comment: @nogs Upload your .blend using blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com and i'll take a look at it for you.

Comment: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=1263" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1263/)

Answer (score 1):

One reason that things are looking strange is that you're editing with the SubSurf modifier turned on. I usually don't show the subsurf in edit mode, but there's nothing wrong with that.

The other thing that's making things act "strange" is that your "Pivot Point" is set to "Individual Origins," instead of "Median." To find that, look for a button that has two overlapping circles, and each circle has a blue dot in the center. It's between the "Display Mode" button and the "Show Manipulator" button. The "Display Mode" button has a wireframe sphere on it, and the "Show Manipulator" button looks like the three-axis manipulator that you see in the viewport.

Click on the "Pivot Point" button and choose the selection that has a single dot between both circles. This is "Median" and is the default. It will behave a bit more like you expect.

With "Individual Origins," it's trying to extrude each face along its own normal. you can find more information in the [Blender Manual](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Fade/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Transform_Control/Pivot_Point/Individual_Origins).

Comment: First, thank you for the answear, but this doesnt seem to change much..
The problem is that the extrudion is all messed up. i try to extrude to the left, it extrudes to some other point. The Z axis does whatever it wants....

Comment: Msybe you can try?
[<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=1263" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1263/)

Comment: Oh, when you extrude, it does choose an axis to constrain to, and it can seem arbitrary. I think the axis it chooses is an average of the normals. Either way, the way I usually solve the problem is by pressing E to extrude, and then immediately pressing Esc. Then, you still have your selection and can move it however you want.

Comment: Lemme know how that works for you, and I'll update my answer.

Comment: That is exactley a problem I have! When I do it, all of the edges are rounded, it looks like I have pressed the I button.